# How can I detect an element underneath an image that I am dragging within a Pointer Event?

Tags: javascript, pointer-events

I have dynamically created a chess board using JavaScript with all the pieces in their starting squares.  I have worked out how to get the pieces to move around on the board but cannot figure out how to detect the square(a paragraph element) under which the piece I am dragging around on the board(an image element). I am using Pointer Events and am pretty sure I need to append the image I am dragging to the square I am dropping it on.

```
let pieces = document.getElementsByTagName('img');


board.addEventListener('pointerdown', (e) =>  {
    e.target.ondragstart = () => {
      return false;
    };
    if(e.target.className.includes('square')){
        return false
    }
    
    
    board.addEventListener('pointerup', removeDots)
    board.addEventListener('pointermove', movePiece)
    //board.addEventListener('pointerover', dropZone)
});

function removeDots(e) {
    console.log(e.target.parentElement)
    board.removeEventListener('pointermove', movePiece)
    board.removeEventListener('pointerup', removeDots)
    
}

function movePiece(e){
    e.target.style.position = 'fixed';
    e.target.style.left = e.pageX - e.target.offsetWidth / 2 + 'px';
    e.target.style.top = e.pageY - e.target.offsetHeight / 2 + 'px';
    

}
```

This portion is what I am using to get the only the pieces moving and not the whole board.  Feel free to let me know if there is an error here.

```
    e.target.hidden = true; 
    let elemBelow = document.elementFromPoint(e.clientX, e.clientY);
    let droppableBelow = elemBelow.closest('p');
    console.log(droppableBelow)
    e.target.hidden = false;
```

I found this on a website and tried implementing it into my code but the droppableBelow only ever returns the original element from where I picked it up from.  Even when I drag it to a new square, drop it and pick it back up.  I am just using plain old JS and have no experience(yet) with Jquery, although I did look for solutions there too.  Everything I found(if I was looking in the correct spot) had to do with just mouse events. (I am also aware of chessboard.js but wish to create my own for the experience)

[For visual reference of my Chess Board](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iGz5M.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using [elementFromPoint()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/elementFromPoint), I found my answer in [elementsFromPoint()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/elementsFromPoint):

```
function dropPiece(e) {
    let clone = e.target.cloneNode(true);
    clone.style.position = 'inherit';
    let position = document.elementsFromPoint(e.clientX, e.clientY);
    position[1].appendChild(clone);
    e.target.remove();
    board.removeEventListener('pointermove', movePiece);
    board.removeEventListener('pointerup', dropPiece);
}
```

Instead of returning the most nested element, it gives an array of all elements from the given coordinates.